# I want to calculate the value of an integer in a text field while ignoring a string of text that is required before the integer?

Tags: java, int, jtextfield, calculation

I am making my own assistant program that connects to a bank management program i wrote. I want the user to be able to type into the command field: add $5 or add $10500 or any other amount. How would i calculate the "10500" while ignoring the "add $". The "add $" is used to check what command the user is typing to perform the action. This is what i have so far.

```
} else if (AssistantFrame.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("add $5")) {

        BankBalance.addToBalance(5);

}
```

This is the code that handles adding the money to the balance.

```
public static void addToBalance(int balanceAdd){

    Commands.setContinuity(0);

    if(fileBalance.exists()) {

            try {
                loadBalance();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            }

            balance += balanceAdd;

            try {
                saveBalance();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            }

            AssistantFrame.updateAssistant("Your balance has been succesfully updated.\nYour new balance is - $" + balance);

    } else {

        AssistantFrame.updateAssistant("Sorry, but you don't seem to have a personal\nbank balance created yet.");

    }
```

Comment: JFormattedTextField perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
String command = AssistantFrame.getCommand();
int amount = Integer.parseInt(command.replaceAll("[^\\d]",""));
BankBalance.addToBalance(amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is iterate through all the chars, check to see if their value is between 48 and 57, inclusive, and if they are, then add them to a String. You will have a String that contains digits only. You can then just parse the String using 'Integer.parseInt(...)'

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use [`String.startsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) and then use [`String.substring(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) before you parse. Like,

```
String command = "add $10";
if (command.startsWith("add $")) {
    int v = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(5));
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Which outputs

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is parsing the command. You can simply the following example if your command will be simple enough:

```
if(command.startsWith("add $")){
   money=command.substring(5);
   todo=ADD;
else if(command.startsWith("something else")){
   ...
   todo=SOMETHING_ELSE;
}
...
```

Or if your commands will be more complex in nature, then go through Lexical Analyser codes.

> ...lexical analysis, lexing or tokenization is the process of converting a sequence of characters (such as in a computer program or web page) into a sequence of tokens (strings with an assigned and thus identified meaning)... [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)

One of such example is: [here](https://github.com/IraKorshunova/JavaCompiler/blob/master/src/lexer/Lexer.java)